# Trouble in reading TCP/IP illustrated Volume 1, first Editon : Section 19.4

Tags: tcp

Ebook link:
[TCP/IP illustrated Volume 1: 19. TCP Interactive Data Flow](http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_int.htm)

Figure 19.6 Time line for Figure 19.5 (watching the Nagle algorithm)
[image: Figure 19.6 Time line for Figure 19.5 (watching the Nagle algorithm)]

> The first change we notice is that all 3 bytes are sent when they're ready (segments 1, 2, and 3). There is no delay—the Nagle algorithm has been disabled.
>
> The next packet we see in the tcpdump output (segment 4) contains byte 5 from the server with an ACK 4. This is wrong. The client immediately responds with an ACK 2 (it is not delayed), not an ACK 6, since it wasn't expecting byte 5 to arrive. It appears a data segment was lost. We show this with a dashed line in Figure 19.8.
>
> How do we know this lost segment contained bytes 2, 3, and 4, along with an ACK 3? The next byte we're expecting is byte number 2, as announced by segment 5. (Whenever TCP receives out-of-order data beyond the next expected sequence number, it normally responds with an acknowledgment specifying the sequence number of the next byte it expects to receive.) **Also, since the missing segment contained bytes 2, 3, and 4, it means the server must have received segment 2, so the missing segment must have specified an ACK 3** (the sequence number of the next byte the server is expecting to receive.) Finally, notice that the retransmission, segment 6, contains data from the missing segment and segment 4. This is called repacketization,

The Author makes me confused , where is the ACK 2 from server(vangogh.login)?
I think the statement should be "it means the server must have received segment 1, so the missing segment must have specified an ACK 2 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, slip expects get the 2nd byte from vangogh.login, but it gets 5th byte;

Second, so we can conclude that 2nd, 3rd, 4th byte was lost in the transmission from vangogh.login to slip;

Third, 2nd, 3rd byte were tansfered form segment 1() send by slip, 4th byte were tansfered form segment 2, and segment 1, segment 2 were received by vangogh.login.

Fourth, so the missing segment must have specified an ACK 3 according to segment 2( 2:3(1) ).